# Issues in initializing labels in Spacy spancat pipeline

Tags: python-3.x, initialization, label, spacy-3, categorization

I am working in setting up a spaCy spancategorizer with multiple labels.
I have annotated my training data using `doc.span[label]` for the different labels, and save it as train/dev data.
I receive this error when I run the training:

*ValueError: [E143] Labels for component 'spancat' not initialized. This can be fixed by calling add_label, or by providing a representative batch of examples to the component's `initialize` method.*

I have added my labels in the *[components.spancat] spans_key* part of the config file.

I have generated an Example object, which contains labels as well, but those labels are not recognized either.

```
def get_examples():
    for pred, gold in zip(all_annotated_pre_shuffled_docs, docs_without_annotations):
        print(pred,gold)
        yield Example(pred, gold)

spancat  = nlp.add_pipe("spancat", before = "textcat")
spancat.initialize(get_examples, nlp=nlp)
```

For the Example,there is a [`parse_gold_doc()`](https://spacy.io/api/example) function not defined in spaCy. It may be that what I am missing?
Please if you can provide some guidance on what I am missing. I am new using spaCy, so additional feedback is very welcome. It has been hard to find examples on the spancategorizer outside Prodigy. Thank you very much.

My doc annotations:

```
     for doc in docs:
         phrase_matches = phrase_matcher(doc)
    
         # Initializaing the SpanGroups for each doc
         for label in labels:
             doc.spans[label]=[]
    
         # phrase_matches detection and labeling of spans, and generation of SpanGrups for each doc
         for match_id, start, end in phrase_matches:
                 match_label = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id]
                 span = doc[start:end]
                 span = Span(doc, start, end, label = match_label)
            
                 # Set up of the SpanGroup for each doc, for the different labels
                 doc.spans[match_label].append(span)
```

for saving my data I am using the following (only train and dev I am using in spaCy):

```
random.shuffle(docs)
n       = len(docs)
n_train = 2*n//3
n_dev   = max(30, 3*n//4 - 2*n//3)
n_test  = n - n_train - n_dev

train_docs = docs[:n_train+1]
dev_docs   = docs[n_train+1: n-n_test]
test_docs  = docs[n-n_test+1:]

# Create and save a collection of training docs
train_docbin = DocBin(docs = train_docs)
train_docbin.to_disk("data/train.spacy")
# Create and save a collection of evaluation docs
dev_docbin = DocBin(docs = dev_docs)
dev_docbin.to_disk("data/dev.spacy")
```

and my configuration file

```
[paths]
train = data/train.spacy
dev = data/dev.spacy
vectors = "en_core_web_lg"
init_tok2vec = null

[system]
gpu_allocator = null
seed = 0

[nlp]
lang = "en"
pipeline = ["tok2vec","tagger","morphologizer","parser","ner","spancat","textcat"]
batch_size = 1000
disabled = []
before_creation = null
after_creation = null
after_pipeline_creation = null
tokenizer = {"@tokenizers":"spacy.Tokenizer.v1"}

[components]

[components.morphologizer]
factory = "morphologizer"
extend = false
overwrite = true
scorer = {"@scorers":"spacy.morphologizer_scorer.v1"}

[components.morphologizer.model]
@architectures = "spacy.Tagger.v2"
nO = null
normalize = false

[components.morphologizer.model.tok2vec]
@architectures = "spacy.Tok2VecListener.v1"
width = ${components.tok2vec.model.encode.width}
upstream = "*"

[components.ner]
factory = "ner"
incorrect_spans_key = null
moves = null
scorer = {"@scorers":"spacy.ner_scorer.v1"}
update_with_oracle_cut_size = 100

[components.ner.model]
@architectures = "spacy.TransitionBasedParser.v2"
state_type = "ner"
extra_state_tokens = false
hidden_width = 64
maxout_pieces = 2
use_upper = true
nO = null

[components.ner.model.tok2vec]
@architectures = "spacy.Tok2VecListener.v1"
width = ${components.tok2vec.model.encode.width}
upstream = "*"

[components.parser]
factory = "parser"
learn_tokens = false
min_action_freq = 30
moves = null
scorer = {"@scorers":"spacy.parser_scorer.v1"}
update_with_oracle_cut_size = 100

[components.parser.model]
@architectures = "spacy.TransitionBasedParser.v2"
state_type = "parser"
extra_state_tokens = false
hidden_width = 128
maxout_pieces = 3
use_upper = true
nO = null

[components.parser.model.tok2vec]
@architectures = "spacy.Tok2VecListener.v1"
width = ${components.tok2vec.model.encode.width}
upstream = "*"

[components.spancat]
factory = "spancat"
max_positive = null
scorer = {"@scorers":"spacy.spancat_scorer.v1"}
spans_key = ['ROOT1', 'ROOT2', 'PERSONAL', 'CHECK_BOX', 'Y/N']
threshold = 0.5

[components.spancat.model]
@architectures = "spacy.SpanCategorizer.v1"

[components.spancat.model.reducer]
@layers = "spacy.mean_max_reducer.v1"
hidden_size = 128

[components.spancat.model.scorer]
@layers = "spacy.LinearLogistic.v1"
nO = null
nI = null

[components.spancat.model.tok2vec]
@architectures = "spacy.Tok2VecListener.v1"
width = ${components.tok2vec.model.encode.width}
upstream = "*"

[components.spancat.suggester]
@misc = "spacy.ngram_suggester.v1"
sizes = [1,2,3]

[components.tagger]
factory = "tagger"
neg_prefix = "!"
overwrite = false
scorer = {"@scorers":"spacy.tagger_scorer.v1"}

[components.tagger.model]
@architectures = "spacy.Tagger.v2"
nO = null
normalize = false

[components.tagger.model.tok2vec]
@architectures = "spacy.Tok2VecListener.v1"
width = ${components.tok2vec.model.encode.width}
upstream = "*"

[components.textcat]
factory = "textcat"
scorer = {"@scorers":"spacy.textcat_scorer.v1"}
threshold = 0.5

[components.textcat.model]
@architectures = "spacy.TextCatEnsemble.v2"
nO = null

[components.textcat.model.linear_model]
@architectures = "spacy.TextCatBOW.v2"
exclusive_classes = true
ngram_size = 1
no_output_layer = false
nO = null

[components.textcat.model.tok2vec]
@architectures = "spacy.Tok2VecListener.v1"
width = ${components.tok2vec.model.encode.width}
upstream = "*"

[components.tok2vec]
factory = "tok2vec"

[components.tok2vec.model]
@architectures = "spacy.Tok2Vec.v2"

[components.tok2vec.model.embed]
@architectures = "spacy.MultiHashEmbed.v2"
width = ${components.tok2vec.model.encode.width}
attrs = ["ORTH","SHAPE"]
rows = [5000,2500]
include_static_vectors = true

[components.tok2vec.model.encode]
@architectures = "spacy.MaxoutWindowEncoder.v2"
width = 256
depth = 8
window_size = 1
maxout_pieces = 3

[corpora]

[corpora.dev]
@readers = "spacy.Corpus.v1"
path = ${paths.dev}
max_length = 0
gold_preproc = false
limit = 0
augmenter = null

[corpora.train]
@readers = "spacy.Corpus.v1"
path = ${paths.train}
max_length = 0
gold_preproc = false
limit = 0
augmenter = null

[training]
dev_corpus = "corpora.dev"
train_corpus = "corpora.train"
seed = ${system.seed}
gpu_allocator = ${system.gpu_allocator}
dropout = 0.1
accumulate_gradient = 1
patience = 1600
max_epochs = 0
max_steps = 20000
eval_frequency = 200
frozen_components = []
annotating_components = []
before_to_disk = null

[training.batcher]
@batchers = "spacy.batch_by_words.v1"
discard_oversize = false
tolerance = 0.2
get_length = null

[training.batcher.size]
@schedules = "compounding.v1"
start = 100
stop = 1000
compound = 1.001
t = 0.0

[training.logger]
@loggers = "spacy.ConsoleLogger.v1"
progress_bar = false

[training.optimizer]
@optimizers = "Adam.v1"
beta1 = 0.9
beta2 = 0.999
L2_is_weight_decay = true
L2 = 0.01
grad_clip = 1.0
use_averages = false
eps = 0.00000001
learn_rate = 0.001

[training.score_weights]
tag_acc = 0.17
pos_acc = 0.08
morph_acc = 0.08
morph_per_feat = null
dep_uas = 0.08
dep_las = 0.08
dep_las_per_type = null
sents_p = null
sents_r = null
sents_f = 0.0
ents_f = 0.17
ents_p = 0.0
ents_r = 0.0
ents_per_type = null
spans_sc_f = 0.17
spans_sc_p = 0.0
spans_sc_r = 0.0
cats_score = 0.17
cats_score_desc = null
cats_micro_p = null
cats_micro_r = null
cats_micro_f = null
cats_macro_p = null
cats_macro_r = null
cats_macro_f = null
cats_macro_auc = null
cats_f_per_type = null
cats_macro_auc_per_type = null

[pretraining]

[initialize]
vectors = ${paths.vectors}
init_tok2vec = ${paths.init_tok2vec}
vocab_data = null
lookups = null
before_init = null
after_init = null

[initialize.components]

[initialize.tokenizer]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[components.spancat.spans_key]` should be a string. You need to save all the spans under a single spans key like `"sc"`. `"sc"` is the default and the easiest to get working with a default config.

You want to train the `spancat` component separately and then add it to an existing pipeline rather than trying to train from the combined config above. The steps would be:

1. Convert your data with all spans saved under `doc.spans["sc"]`
2. Create a config with `spacy init config -p spancat -o accuracy` (this will use `en_core_web_lg` vectors)
3. Train
4. Add the new `spancat` component to `en_core_web_lg` after replacing the spancat `tok2vec` listener with an internal `tok2vec`

   ```py
   nlp_spancat = spacy.load("spancat_model")
   nlp_spancat.replace_listeners("tok2vec", "spancat", ["model.tok2vec"])
   nlp_combined = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")
   nlp_combined.add_pipe("spancat", source=nlp_spancat)
   nlp_combined.to_disk("combined_model")
   ```

You can do the same thing as above with `spacy assemble` and a config that sources all the components, but the steps above are simpler.

Comment: Thank you so much for all that detail! You made my day :) At this point my only question is how to save all labels into just one label "sc"?

Comment: The `Span` objects have the individual labels. `doc.spans["sc"].append(span)`

Comment: Thank you very much. I see you know a lot about this SpanCategorizer. It has been hard for me to find documentation and examples. Do you have some good sources you would like to share?

Comment: Hi abb. I have implemented your guidance and it is giving predictions!! Yay :) You are a hero! There is so much to learn about. My question now is how can I add the textcat pipeline after spancat? This span-categorizations will be useful for the my text-categorization so want the model to use it. Please if you can help me with your wisdom. Thanks again,

Comment: One more thing, Abb, I am using spancat = nlp_combined.add_pipe("spancat", source=nlp_spancat) and score = spancat.predict([doc]). The scores look very low , as for example [1.6556357e-04... ] for text that were used for training and I would have expected close to 1 for that first label. What can be happening? The training pipeline is showing SCORE 0.87, which is pretty good. Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: If you run `add_pipe` without replacing the listeners the scores could be nonsense. In general: run the whole pipeline with `nlp(text)` and look at `doc.spans["sc"]` and `doc.spans["sc"].attrs["scores"]` for the scores.

Comment: @aab I am facing similar issue with blank spacy model. I can successfully train my NER model on custom labels starting with spacy blank en model but when I am trying to convert the ents to spans and train the model I get an error.
Can you please have a look on my Q? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73764895/cant-run-the-spacy-spancat-spancategorizer-model

Comment: @Paola can you please share your code or git? I have the same issue with spacy blank model. Would you be so kind and share your knowledge?

Comment: Hi Steve, at this moment I have stopped working on the spancat. I wasn't able to make it work and give good predictions. Following Abb guidance I was able to get predictions, but were really bad. I may resume spancat work in 3 weeks or so. Once I do, will share anything that is working. Please do the same. All the best,

Comment: Hi Steve. I am just coming back to the spancategorizer, and found this article that can be helpful. Did you resolve your problem? https://cees-roele.medium.com/detecting-toxic-spans-with-spacy-c5533786bbf8

Comment: Hi @abb, I am back able to run the spancategorizer with your guidance Thanks a lot. Now I need to include my textcategorizer after. I want to help the textcategorizer with a previous spancategorization since the textcategorizer is failing on long text predictions. I expect the spancat could provide some focus. How do you recommend doing this? I am having trouble understanding when I need or do not need a new listener, and I assume I would use the same annotated data with a `span` and a `cats` sections. Please, if you could share some of your wisdom, it would be very appreciated. Many thanks

Comment: This kind of question is a better fit for the spacy discussion forum on github: https://github.com/explosion/spacy/discussions

Comment: @SteveS, I followed the discussion in this questions, in case you are interested: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/11663