# Adding Span Categorizer to Spacy at the end of pipeline is not working

Tags: python, spacy

> I want to add spancat using default model at the end of my pipeline as shown.

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
from spacy.pipeline.spancat import DEFAULT_SPANCAT_MODEL
config = {
    "threshold": 0.5,
    "spans_key": "labeled_spans",
    "max_positive": None,
    "model": DEFAULT_SPANCAT_MODEL,
    "suggester": {"@misc": "spacy.ngram_suggester.v1", "sizes": [1, 2, 3]},
}
spancat = nlp.add_pipe("spancat", config=config)
optimizer = nlp.create_optimizer()
spancat.add_label("SPANCAT")
optimizer = nlp.initialise()
```

> This gives me the following error

```
ValueError: [E955] Can't find table(s) lexeme_norm for language 'en' in spacy-lookups-data. Make sure you have the package installed or provide your own lookup tables if no default lookups are available for your language.
```

> Why is this happening? I have read that for text categorizer training, you need to start with blank("en"), but I want to use "en_core_web_sm". What should I do?
> [I want result as follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHyfq.png)

Answer (score 2):

You do not want to do this. Calling `nlp.initialize()` on the whole pipeline will reset all the components in the pipeline including existing components like the tagger, and reinitializing everything is why it's trying to reload a lookups table that's already saved as part of `en_core_web_sm`.

Instead, follow the same steps described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/73659974, except without `-o accuracy` so that you train a component without vectors to be able to add it to `en_core_web_sm`:

1. Convert your data with all spans saved under `doc.spans["sc"]`
2. Create a config with `spacy init config -p spancat`
3. Train
4. Add the new `spancat` component to `en_core_web_sm` after replacing the spancat `tok2vec` listener with an internal `tok2vec`

   ```py
   nlp_spancat = spacy.load("spancat_model")
   nlp_spancat.replace_listeners("tok2vec", "spancat", ["model.tok2vec"])
   nlp_combined = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
   nlp_combined.add_pipe("spancat", source=nlp_spancat)
   nlp_combined.to_disk("combined_model")
   ```

To make sure that your `spancat` component has the exact same base settings as `en_core_web_sm` (which includes the `lexeme_norm` lookups table from the error above), you can use this callback in your spancat config:

https://spacy.io/api/top-level#copy_from_base_model

```ini
[initialize.before_init]
@callbacks = "spacy.copy_from_base_model.v1"
tokenizer = "en_core_web_sm"
vocab = "en_core_web_sm"
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to initialse successfully. However, how did you load spancat_model. It says no such model exists

Comment: `spancat_model` is a placeholder name for the pipeline that you trained in step 3. Usually the path would look like `output/model-best` from `spacy train -o output`.